# iphone keyboard button popup

Tags: iphone, button, keyboard, popup

I have a custom view with buttons for an iPhone app and I use it as an input view for a uitextfield. So when I click on the button I want the key to popup so the user the see what's under their finger, very much like the default keyboard in iOS. Some one already asked a similar question like this but no answer, I have done some research but couldn't find anything so I respectfully ask this again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the behavior you want by code, miming the default keyboard design.
This means you have to create a method that shows what it is under the finger of the user while he touches your button/key and a method that then passes your key value and removes your fake view when the user release your button.

```
underFingerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:THE_FAKE_IMAGE]];

// Call this at touchDownEvent
- (void)mimeDefaultKeyboardFirstPart
{
  underFingerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
  [myKeyboard addSubview:underFingerImageView];
}

// call this at touchUpEvent
- (void)mimeDefaultKeyboardSecondPart
{
  [underFingerImageView removeFromSuperview];

  // Do what you want
}
```